# Customize focused state appearance on tab item in Xamarin Forms app, Android implementation

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, focus

In my cross-platform Xamarin Forms app, specifically on Android, I want to be able to customize the appearance of the items in the navigation bar of the `Xamarin.Forms.TabbedPage`. In particular, I want to be able to change the background for focused items in the bar from a solid light grey cropped circle (see image below) to a different shape, for example a green rectangular frame (the actual shape is not important).

I know how to change the background for an item depending on state, my problem is I cannot find which style or similar I need to modify to change the background for the navigation items in `TabbedPage`.

Typically for the Android app project of a Xamarin Forms app, the *Tabbar.axml* file is contained in the *Resources/Layout* folder, but any change I make in this file does not seem to apply to the appearance of the navigation tab. For example, I tried to add the following line:

```
app:tabBackground="@drawable/background_states"
```

but I could not see any indication that my change was applied.

I have also tried identifying more generally which Android style to override, but to no avail.

Can anybody give me a push in the right direction for the solution to my problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the tab bar is placed at the bottom of the page the bar is represented by a `BottomNavigationView`. I therefore need to apply the desired background style via a custom `TabbedPage` renderer.

In the renderer, override `OnElementChanged` as follows:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TabbedPage> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    if (e.NewElement == null) return;

    // Identify first (only) bottom navigation view in collection of element children.
    var bottomNavigationView = GetBottomNavigationView(ViewGroup);

    // Apply a custom border style for the item background.
    bottomNavigationView.ItemBackground =
        Resources?.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.background_states, Context?.Theme);
}
```

where `GetBottomNavigationView` is a method for traversing the tree of element children and needs to be separately implemented (left out here for brevity). The drawable resource `background_states` is the selector used to apply different backgrounds depending on state.